# What will be the replacement for the sql operation SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(year,' ', 2), ' ',-1) in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table 'movie' in which some of the years is having extra character separated by space :
`array(['I 2018', 'XVII 2016', '1958', 'I 2017'])` . I want to get the only year removing anything non-numeric .

I was using mysql to get this done , using something like :
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(year,' ', 2), ' ',-1)`

The code I was using in mysql is :

```sql
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(year,' ', 2), ' ',-1) as year from movie
```

I read that there is no such function in sqlite3 , so tried to use substr like :

```sql
select substr(SUBSTR(year," ",2),' ',-1) from movie;
```

But answer is not what i expected .

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) for `substr()` to see why that isn't working? Hint: Another function that might be useful is also documented on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your string pattern is based on a space between text and the number you nedd 
your you could try
You could try replacing the sustring_index for space  (and trimming)

```
select  trim(replace("I 2018", SUBSTRING_INDEX("I 2018", " ", 1),''))
select  trim(replace("I 18", SUBSTRING_INDEX("I 2018", " ", 1),''))

select  trim(replace(your_col, SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_col, " ", 1),''))
from your_table
```

or if your db don't support substring_index  you can  use instr()

```
select  trim(substr( "I 2018",  instr( "I 2018", ' '), 100))  ;

select  trim(substr(your_column,  instr( your_column, ' '), 100)) 
from your_table ;
```

Comment: substring_index is not supported in sqlite

Comment: it works , but could you please mind explaining the second method , how it is workin ?

Comment: then instr() function retrive the position of the space the substr() use this value for obtain the substring starting form the postion of the space to the right (100 char)  and the result is trimmed  off the space... hope is clear  ..

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaroud . I just selected the last 4 charactes from the column and it gave me the answer .

```sql
select SUBSTR(year,-4) from movie;
```